# Persistent object in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am fairly new to node and backend work in general. We are using express at work for a pretty large monolith application that houses all of our endpoints and services. My task is to grab a property that comes in on the request object (i.e. `request.someObject`), and use it in several services. In a DOM environment I would use something like localStorage or sessionStorage to store that data, and then reuse it where needed across the application. Im going to try and explain a little further with code:

Endpoint

```
    router.route('/:cartId/generatePaymentLink')
    .post(jsonParser, urlParser, function(request, response, next) {
        var theObject = request.someObject;
        // need to pass theObject to several services
    });
```

Services are stored within separate files, here is an example of one

```
var paypalInfo = new Paypal({
    userId: theObject.user_id,
    password: theObject.password
});
```

I can pass it through parameters to the services that use data, but its used in several different places and would have to be defined in those individual services. Is there a way to create a persistent object/config file that I can just import and have that data, or something like sessionStorage in the DOM?

EDIT: Not a database, looking for another solution. For performance reasons we are avoiding this

Comment: Like, a **database**?

Comment: @Pointy Will clarify in the question

Comment: You could use export / require mechanism. Export your variable, and import it in the desired service. But I don't see any drawback to use parameters ... Or database as said by @Pointy

Comment: I believe nodejs also has a `global` type variable. You can read more about it here: https://www.hacksparrow.com/global-variables-in-node-js.html. Not sure if it's best practice though, as others have said, a database, or `module.exports` would fit better :)

Comment: @Ko2r Regarding the parameters; it works, but it has to go through a lot of other services to reach where it is being used. Im just wondering if a better option exists, and I'm going to try to export the object and import it where needed right now. As for the database, that was the first solution I came up with, but it impacted performance way too much to be considered over the parameters method.

Comment: OK so maybe using objects and export should be a way to go

Comment: @Ko2r Worked perfectly, thank you!